# Creating a container of matrices with different dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to make multiple arrays with different dimensions in Matlab.
Is there a way to do this inside a "for" loop?

For example, I would like to create a matrix A with dimensions 100x100, then with 200x200,etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `zeros` function instead of creating your array inside of a loop.

Something like:

```
B = zeros(m,n)
A = zeros(m,n)
```

This will be much faster initially (since the array is not having to be resized every time you add an element); you can then iterate over it later and add whatever values you need.

EDIT: I should clarify, the zeros function creates an m X n matrix (or an array if you leave off the second argument) and fills it with all zeros. It's a good starting point for constructing large arrays.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a cell in which you store the matrices:

```
a = cell(10,1);
for n=1:10
    a{n} = zeros(n*100,n*100);
end
```

Note: to get an item from a cell you should use {} instead of (). a{1} returns the first matrix, a(1) returns a cell which contains that matrix.

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html

Comment: If you know the size of the array ahead of time, you should preallocate. I.e. write `a=cell(10,1);`